# How can I sample down a time series by providing only the sampling rate?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am having a series `vec` which has been sampled at 2000Hz. What I would like to do is to sample this series down in 50Hz steps. My problem is that I do not quite understand how I can do this with pandas.

I do not quite understand how I can wrap my `vec` into a `DataFrame` and set the time stamps using `pd.date_range` accordingly.

The code I *could* show you is plain wrong, thus I cannot really show you what I did so far. But I can show you in pseudo Python what I'd like to do:

```
# Get a date range for vec 
date_range = pd.date_range(len(vec), sampling_rate=2000, unit='Hz')
# Create a DataFrame for the 2000Hz series
df_2k = pd.DataFrame(vec, index=date_range)

# Sample down to 1950Hz, 1900Hz, ..
df_1950Hz = df_2k.resample(sampling_rate=1950, unit='Hz')
df_1900Hz = df_2k.resample(sampling_rate=1900, unit='Hz')
```

Any idea how I can do this?

I think what could also work is something like

```
 df_1950Hz = df_2k.drop_every(nth_sample=int(2000/50))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, construct a period from your frequency:

```
freq = 1950
period = '{}N'.format(int(1e9 / freq))
```

This gives you `'512820N'` which Pandas understands as nanoseconds.  Then:

```
df2k.resample(period).mean() # you could use e.g. `last()` instead
```

As for your initial index, maybe you want this:

```
freq = 2000
period = '{}N'.format(int(1e9 / freq))
index = pd.date_range(start, periods=len(vec), freq=period)
```

Where `start` is arbitrary.

Comment: Hm, this does not work for me. How did you initialize `df2k`? Getting `ValueError: Invalid frequency: 512820.0N`

Comment: @displayname: Sorry I fixed it, by adding `int()` to get 512820N instead of 512820.0N.  Try the code now.

Comment: Would be nice if you could just pass 50hz :-)

Comment: As @piRSquared mentioned I would prefer a simpler interface - maybe pandas provides that someday. For now your solution works fine for me. Thank you :)

Comment: @displayname: Just make a function: `def Hz(n): return '{}N'.format(int(1e9 / freq))` and then you can say `df.resample(Hz(1950))`.  Easy.